# Box with 2 columns and fixing text length to match column width

Tags: php, html, css, button

How do i get a box that has 2 columns. Column 1 fits text in it and column 2 has the "Contact" button. For now my code is placing the button below the text. The reason i want to have 2 columns is because i want the length of the text to fit only in its column. or is there a simple way. Using bootstrap 3.3.7. Thanks.

```
 <div class="container c2">
    <div class="row">
         <?php
            include('dbcon.php');

            $state="Johor";
            $query = "SELECT * from mhc_donee where donee_state='$state'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            if($result){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo ' <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="row">
                    <img src="images/'.$row["donee_image"].'" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                    <p>' . $row["donee_name"] . '</p>
                    <p>' . $row["donee_address"] . '</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">CONTACT</button>
                    </div>
                </div>';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: `<div class="row">` is wrong on the button div, this adds a new row, hence why the button is  underneath

Comment: @DarrenSweeney  deleted that but still the button is below

Comment: `<div>` is a block-level element that defaults to `width:100%`. So you have to do something to give those divs the desired width. Like `float: left` or `inline-block` and set the `width: ...%`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">Address goes here</div>
<div class="col-md-2">Button goes here</div>
</div>
```

You can further tweak the grid needed for your needs.